# How I can make a query to select 3 group of name

Tags: sql, psql

I want to ask some question about the query select

```
plants (
  name,
  sci_name,
  common_names,
  family,
  image_url,
  aspca_url
); 
toxicity (
  plant_id,
  animal, 
  toxic,
  clinical_signs
```

```
static async searchNameAndToxicity ( name )
    {
        const plantAndToxicityRes = await db.query(
          `SELECT 
            plants.id, 
            plants.name, 
            plants.sci_name,
            plants.common_names,
            toxicity.animal, 
            toxicity.toxic, 
            toxicity.clinical_signs
          FROM plants
          LEFT JOIN toxicity ON plants.id = toxicity.plant_id
          WHERE lower(sci_name) LIKE '%' || $1 || '%' 
            OR lower(common_names) LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
            OR lower(name) LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
        LIMIT 3 ;`,
          [name.toLowerCase()]
        );
        
        console.log( plantAndToxicityRes );
   
        if (!plantAndToxicityRes) {
          throw new NotFoundError(`No plant and toxicity: ${name}`);
        }
        
        const plantAndToxicityDetails = plantAndToxicityRes.rows;
      
        const combinedData = plantAndToxicityDetails.reduce((result, current) => {
            const { name, sci_name, common_names, animal, toxic, clinical_signs } = current;
            const key = `${name}-${sci_name}-${common_names}-${clinical_signs}`;
          
            if (!result[key]) {
              result[key] = { name, sci_name,common_names, animals: [], clinical_signs };
            }
          
            result[key].animals.push({ animal, toxic });
          
            return result;
          }, {});
        
          return Object.values(combinedData);
    };
```

it will return

```
[
    {
        "name": "Achira",
        "sci_name": "Canna edulis",
        "common_names": "Canna, Arrowroot",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": false
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bluebottle",
        "sci_name": "Centaurea cyanus",
        "common_names": "Cornflower, Bachelors Buttons",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": true
            },
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Apricot",
        "sci_name": "Prunus armeniaca",
        "common_names": "Group also includes Plum, Peach, Cherry",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": true
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": true
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": true
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": "Stems, leaves, seeds contain cyanide, particularly toxic in the process of wilting: brick red mucous membranes, dilated pupils, difficulty breathing, panting, shock."
    },
    {
        "name": "Baby’s Tears",
        "sci_name": "Hypoestes phyllostachya",
        "common_names": "Polka Dot Plant, Measles Plant, Flamingo Plant, Freckle Face, Pink Splash",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": false
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": "Mild vomiting, diarrhea"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bachelors Buttons",
        "sci_name": "Centaurea cyanus",
        "common_names": "Cornflower, Bluebottle",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": true
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bamboo",
        "sci_name": "Phyllostachys aurea",
        "common_names": "Golden Bamboo, Fishpole Bamboo",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": false
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bead Tree",
        "sci_name": "Melia azedarach",
        "common_names": "China Ball Tree, Paradise Tree, Persian Lilac, White Cedar, Japanese Bead Tree, Texas Umbrella Tree, Pride-of-India, Chinaberry Tree",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": true
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": true
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": true
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": "Diarrhea, vomiting, salivation, depression, weakness, and seizures. Ripe fruit (berries) most toxic but also bark, leaves, and flowers."
    },
    {

        "name": "Callistemon Brachyandrus",
        "sci_name": "Callistemon species",
        "common_names": "Weeping Bottlebrush, Prickly Bottlebrush, Crimson Bottlebrush, Bottlebrush, Callistemon brachyandrus",
        "animals": [
            {
                "animal": "cat",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "dog",
                "toxic": false
            },
            {
                "animal": "horse",
                "toxic": false
            }
        ],
        "clinical_signs": ""
    }
```

the plant has multiple toxicity. I already make a combine function to cut off the duplicate of name, sci_name, commom_names and clinical_signs for the animal and toxic I combine to be animals. However, I can't figure out how to get the data for group 3 plant name.
Anyone has an idea to solve this.